# Finding integral values of $3$ different variables.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers, natural-numbers

I'm stuck between a proof.
This is where I've reached

> $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=4abc$
>   where $a,b,c$ are 3 distinct positive integers.

This will complete my proof

> If I prove that
>   $(a+b+c)=abc$ from above

I know that it's true and answer is $(a,b,c)= (1,2,3)$ but I can't find those missing steps in between.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its of log though. So I didn't bother to write it full.

Comment: Yes I needed to solve this${(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\over abc}=2^2$ i.e. $\log_2 [{(a+1)\over a}.{(b+1)\over b}.{(c+1)\over c}]=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$ a={bc+b+c+1\over 3bc-b-c-1}$$ Since $a$ and $bc+b+c+1$ are positive so is $3bc-b-c-1$. Since $a\geq 1$ we have $$3bc-b-c-1\leq bc+b+c+1$$
This is equivalent to $$(b-1)(c-1)\leq 2$$
Can you finish?

Comment: @ChristianF- thx.